# ReactJS Object.keys().length returning number of values rather than length of array of keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use Object.keys() to obtain an array of the keys from a JSON file with the following format:

```
[
{
    "Var1": "01-Dec-2019 00:00:00",
    "Var2": 14.55169
},
{
    "Var1": "01-Dec-2019 00:10:00",
    "Var2": 14.74149
},
{
    "Var1": "01-Dec-2019 00:20:00",
    "Var2": 13.26103
}]
```

Javascript:

```
import data from "../Data/test3data.json";

var test  = Object.keys(this.state.data).length;
```

When I evaluate this it returns the number of total data points (in my case 40,000) instead of 2. I can't seem to figure out why.

Oddly if I try to display the whole object I get the following error

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Var1, Var2})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this line:

`import data from "../Data/test3data.json";`

`data` is equal to:

```
[
{
    "Var1": "01-Dec-2019 00:00:00",
    "Var2": 14.55169
},
{
    "Var1": "01-Dec-2019 00:10:00",
    "Var2": 14.74149
},
{
    "Var1": "01-Dec-2019 00:20:00",
    "Var2": 13.26103
}]
```

So it is an array of objects. For example, `data[0]` is equal:

```
{
    "Var1": "01-Dec-2019 00:00:00",
    "Var2": 14.55169
}
```

So, `Object.keys(this.state.data)` is `[0, 1, 2]`, because array indexes are the keys. And length of `[0, 1, 2]` is total objects count.

If you want to get `Var1`, `Var2` keys, you should do this:

`Object.keys(this.state.data[0])`

`Object.keys(this.state.data[0]).length`

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.data` is an array of data points.

`Object.keys(this.state.data)` returns the indices of all of those data points in the array.

`Object.keys(this.state.data).length` returns the number of total points.

To access a specific item of this array, you need to use f.e. `this.state.data[0]`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an array as when I try to display it React specifically says "×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Var1, Var2}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: @5----------------- It is an array. The error is because it tries to display the first element of the array, which is an object with keys `Var1` and `Var2`, and thus can't be used as a React child. But it is correctly trying to iterate over the array. If you transform the array of data points into a format you can pass directly to React you can display it.